# ajax importing json content from php to edge animate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, adobe-edge

I am working on this project in edge animate for a school assignment.
I have a database on my school webspace and I need to import some data from that database into my edge animate project.

I've been looking on the internet how to do this and these pictures show what I have so far. It still has a javascript error, but I can't figure out what. If I could just get that javascript error sorted, I can add code do some things with the array.

I collect the data from the database in a php-array and I want to save it in an array in javascript so I can display anything from inside that array on different places I want to.

[image: edge animate code]

[image: php code]

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element

Comment: i do get the console.log('start'); and then i get the error

Comment: try to comment all the lines that start with console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because $.ajax is a jquery function, therefore you have to import this libary.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function Load()
    {
        console.log('start ajax query...');

        var delivery;

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: { foo: "bar" }
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            delivery=data;
            console.log(data);
            console.log('...all fine');
        });
    }

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "firing load function..." );
    Load();
});

</script>
```

**PHP Script**

dont modify the header, simply echo the return of json_encode().

```
<?php
/**
 * FILE test.php
 */
    echo json_encode(array('foo'=>'bar'));
?>
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning the script with the link for jquery, silly of me to forget that. i updated the code and now it works, i can get back to working with my data tomorrow ^^

Comment: you are welcome! Plz. accept my answer, so other can find this thread.